# Batch FTP for managing files in my domain

Tags: ftp, batch-file

I use cpanel to upload everything to my websites, but the problem is that I have to browse, select and upload each and every image, page or file individually. Is there a way I can do this as a batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my thing FileZilla .......

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NcFTPput](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/).

Answer (score 0):

Windows comes with a primitive FTP client which you can automate your file transfer. See [here](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsFtpBatchScript.php) for example on how to use it. Also see `ftp /?`. For anything more complicated, use a programming language with good FTP support (eg Perl/Python)

Answer (score 0):

[FTP Sync](http://www.cyberkiko.com/page/FTPSync.aspx) is an excellent tool. It just copies over the files that are required. You can set it up so that at a click of a button your site is updated.